# Finding $n$ such that $a^{17n} - a^2$ is divisible by $311$ for any integer $a$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find a positive integer $n$ such that for any integer $a^{17n} - a^2$ is divisible by $311$.

---

I have no idea really where to take this question. It is a part c of an exam. Part a looked for a primality test on $311$ and part b asked me to compute $13$ to the power of $932$ mod $311$.

Comment: Hint: What can you say about $a^{311}\pmod{311}$?

Comment: [This](http://arxiv.org/ftp/math/papers/0001/0001012.pdf) paper might help!. Also note that 311 is a prime.

Comment: How did you solve parts a and b?

Comment: @Anurag That "paper" is not helpful.

Comment: @TMM. I wanted to convey sarcasm.

Comment: @TMM, I solved part a by the following: sqrt(311) is roughly 17. All primes equal to or smaller than 17 do not divide 311 evenly and therefore 311 is prime. I don't even know how I did part b. Its a bit of a mess. You use Fermat's Little Theorem.

Comment: @Roy: Part b should not be a big mess if you use FLT well. In any case, part c is also about using FLT, so I suggest you study and practice using FLT even more. (If you're "fluent" with FLT, then b should also be easy...)

Comment: Roy: please consider accepting some answers to your questions. You can accept one answer per question asked. To accept an answer, just click on the grey $\large \checkmark$ to the left of the answer you'd like to accept. The check mark turns green, and you get two reputation points on every question you've accepted an answer to.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** As $311$ is prime, there exists a primitive root modulo $311$.

Let $a$ be a primitive root modulo $311$.
Then $a$ is invertible modulo 311

$$a^{17n} \equiv a^2 \pmod {311} \Rightarrow a^{17n-2} \equiv 1 \pmod {311}$$

As $a$ is a primitive root, it means that $310$ must divide $17n-2$.

Find the some $n$ so this happens, and then show that it works for all $a$.

Answer (score 1):

As $311$ is prime, either $311|a$ or $(311,a)=1$

If $311|a, 311|(a^{17n}-a^2)$

Else  $(311,a)=1$ so, $311|(a^{17n}-a^2)\implies 311|(a^{17n-2}-1)\iff a^{17n-2}\equiv1\pmod {311}$

As $311$ is prime, the order of $a$  can be $311-1=310$ and its divisors, the highest order will be $310$ in case of primitive roots

$\implies 310$ must divide  $17n-2$

So, $17n-2=310m$ for some integer $m$

Using continued fraction  $$\frac{310}{17}=18+\frac4{17}=18+\frac1{\frac{17}4}=18+\frac1{4+\frac14}$$

The previous [convergent](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Convergent.html) of $\frac{310}{17}$ is $18+\frac14=\frac{73}4$

Using the Theorem $#3$ of [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_continued_fraction), $17\cdot73-310\cdot4=1$

$\implies17n-310m=2(17\cdot73-310\cdot4)$

$\implies 17(n-146)=310(m-8)$

$\implies \frac{17(n-146)}{310}=m-8$ which is an integer

$\implies310|17(n-146)$

$\implies310|(n-146)$ as $(17,310)=1$

$\implies n-146=310r$ for some integer $r$

Comment: The continued fraction method is interesting. I guess I would just have solved $17n \equiv 2 \mod{310}$ using CRT on the $3$ divisors of $310$.

Comment: @TMM, we can reduce to two divisors $31,5$ as $n$ must be even